# How to get percentage similarity between two float values dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, jupyter

This is what I'm imagining. Here's a sample table:

| Col A | Col B | Similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.0 | 5.0 | 1.000 |
| 3.8 | 2.3 | 0.700 |
| 1.3 | 6.7 | 0.300 |
| 2.7 | 8.5 | 0.350 |
| 2.9 | 2.9 | 1.000 |

What algorithm should I use to do this?

Comment: I only know how to compare two strings by importing strsim and using jarowinkler similarity. Can you demonstrate that by using ipynb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an arbitrary similarity function which returns something between 1 and 0 this is really simple but it would work.

```
df['similarity'] = df['Col A'] / df['Col B']
df.loc[df['similarity'] > 1, 'similarity'] = 1 / df['similarity']
```

Comment: I need a percentage. Not 1 and 0. There should be closeness between two values like 7 and 8 which isn't far apart. It could be 80% similar.

Comment: Yeah, this would work. If you want to have 80 instead of 0.8 you can just multiply by 100

Comment: can you demonstrate it?

Comment: you would just add ```df['similarity'] *= 100``` at the end

Comment: what algorithm is this called?

Comment: We can call it the Alparslan algorithm :D It does not have a name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
x = df.max(axis=1)
y = abs(df['Col A']- df['Col B'])
df['Similarity'] = 1-(y/x)
```

---

**df:**

```
    Col A   Col B   Similarity
0   5.0     5.0     1.000000
1   3.8     2.3     0.605263
2   1.3     6.7     0.194030
3   2.7     8.5     0.317647
4   2.9     2.9     1.000000
```